# How to find video tags in html using python's selectolax parser

Tags: python, html5-video, html-parsing

I have to find all the video tags in an html page using python's selectolax.parser package in order to download them to the disk. 
I can't find any examples for this specific usage.

Thanks.

for example:
this is the html I want to parse:
For example, this is the html I'm trying to parse:

```
\<video width="320" height="240" controls=""\>\n\t\t<source src="movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4">\n\t\t<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </video>
```

I need to get the img 'src' using selectolax

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Yo u are asking a question without any context. The least you could do is add a few lines of code where you performs the actions you do know how to. For example, loading of the HTML page into an object from the package, and/or the loop you are then going to use in order to download the videos. This will let people answer your question without having to speculate the context.

Comment: added more context

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from selectolax creator Artem Golubin :

-> Please see an example: https://dumpz.org/aBDkpZ3STSZ8